# Mercurial "no username supplied" error on Mac

Tags: macos, version-control, mercurial

I've just installed Mercurial on my OSX Mountain Lion Max (10.8) and on my first commit I'm getting the error:

```
abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")
```

I've seen a load of answers which suggest I need to create or copy a file form a certain location and paste it into another location and add my username and email to the document.

If that is the right thing to do:

- Where is the file I need to copy (or what is the file called that I need to create)
- Where do I put that file
- Do I just need to add the following two lines to the file?

  ```
  [ui]
  username = Your Name <your@email.com>
  ```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Another question which is the same as this but doesn't give me enough information to fix the problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329023/mercurial-error-abort-no-username-supplied

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That file is named `.hgrc` and it is located in your home directory. If you just append those lines to `~/.hgrc` and everything should be fine.

An extremely detailed overview of the Mercurial configuration file is located [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html).

Another less convient way is to pass `-u your@email.com` on the command line.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Which directory is the home directory?

Comment: If you open up a terminal, it is the default directory. You can also get to your home directory by `cd ~`

Comment: OK.  Home directory found (thanks).  But there's no .hgrc file in there.  I just installed (successfully I think) Mercurial.  Is there a way of seeing hidden files?

Comment: That file is not created by default. Use `echo -e '[ui]\nusername = Name <n@m.com>' > .hgrc` will create the file

Comment: Chris!  I've upvoted your answer for the -u tipoff - thanks so much.  But I'm still no closer to locating or creating the hgrc file.  The echo command didn't help - still no file anywhere on my machine.  You're probably sick of helping me out, but if you know any reason why I can't find the hgrc file after running that echo, let me know.  Thanks again.

Comment: The file has most likely been created, but it is a hidden file. Try `ls -a` at the command line to see it.